# Theorems in the form of "if and only if" such that the proof of one direction is extremely EASY to prove and the other one is extremely HARD

Tags: soft-question, big-list

I believe this is a common phenomenon in mathematics, but surprisingly, no such list has been created on this site. I don't know if it's of value, just out of curiosity, I want to see more examples. So my request is:

Theorems in the form of "if and only if" that the proof of one direction is extremely **EASY**, or intuitive, or make use of some standard techniques (e.g. diagram chasing), while the other one is extremely **HARD**, or counterintuitive, or require a certain amount of creativity. **The 'if and only if' formulation should be as natural as possible.**

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know this question is somewhat ill-posed. A better one: [Theorems in the form of “if and only if” such that the proofs of BOTH directions are nontrivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069590/theorems-in-the-form-of-if-and-only-if-such-that-the-proofs-of-both-directions)

Comment: One of my college professors likened this phenomenon to running one's palm along one's face. *Down is easy; up is not.*

Comment: That's a good metaphor!

Comment: The reason nobody has created such a list may be the fact that **most** (nontrivial) "iff" theorems belong on your list. It would be more interesting to see a list of "iff" theorems where both directions are nontrivial.

Comment: @bof done, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069590/theorems-in-the-form-of-if-and-only-if-such-that-the-proofs-of-both-directions

Comment: For those who are complaining the question is too broad, give some advice on how to make it more specific.

Comment: You cannot make such a question more specific. You are asking for a list of things of a certain nature, where that set is known to be enormous. Any answer is either just one among many with no way to determine a clear "best" or requires thousands of pages to sufficiently answer in one go. This is textbook classic VTC:TB.

Comment: @Blue Down is easy. Through is not.

Comment: Any difficult theorem of the form "Every widget is a special widget" is essentially "An object is a widget iff it is a special widget"; the "if" direction is trivial and the "only if" direction is difficult.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"A compact 3-manifold is simply-connected if and only if it is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere."

One direction [only if] is the Poincaré conjecture.  The other direction shouldn't be too bad hopefully.

Answer (score 31):

Let $n$ be a positive integer. The equation $x^n+y^n=z^n$ is solvable in positive integers $x,y,z$ iff $n\le2$.

Answer (score 12):

The bisectors of two angles of a triangle are of equal length if and only if the two bisected angles are equal.  If the two angles are equal, the triangle is isosceles and the proof is very easy.  However proving that a triangle must be isosceles if the bisectors of two of its angles are of equal length seems to be quite difficult.

Comment: The [Steiner–Lehmus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner%E2%80%93Lehmus_theorem).

Answer (score 9):

Integers $a * b = 944871836856449473$ and $b > a > 1$

iff

$a = 961748941$ and $b = 982451653$

*If* is trivial multiplication. *Only if* requires large prime factorization.

Comment: The hard direction only requires primality testing, not factorization.

Answer (score 8):

All planar graphs are $n$-colorable iff $n\ge4$.

Answer (score 7):

The difficult part is not as difficult as some of the other answers, but perhaps the "if and only if" formulation is more natural: [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) that a graph is planar if and only if it does not have a subgraph which is a subdivision of either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.

Answer (score 6):

The product of topological spaces is compact if and only if all of them are compact. One direction is trivial because the projections are continuous and surjective functions. The another direction, well, is the axiom of choice.

Comment: Assuming they're all non-empty.

Comment: Actually, the projections always being surjective is also equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: @MarcPaul Would you mind explain a bit on why that is the case? I thought the projection of a product set onto its component looks pretty constructive to me.

Comment: @BgbearZzz Axiom of choice is equivalent to the statement that a product of non-empty sets is non-empty. So if AoC fails, the image of the projection map can be empty. And indeed, equipping each set with the discrete topology, and making sure that at least one of the sets is infinite, you obtain a contradiction to the 'easy' direction of the statement.

Answer (score 4):

An even integer $n$ is the sum of two primes iff $n>2$.

("If" is [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), which is still open. "Only if" is trivial.)

Comment: There may be chances that Goldbach's conjecture is wrong...

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb R^n$ has the structure of a real division algebra iff $n=1,2,4$ or $8$.